# Is a DLL with only constants needed in distribution?

Tags: c#, dll, compilation, constants

I've created two executable projects which depend on a single class library.

The class library contains only classes and constants (no variables or functions), and is used to store application-level protocol information for communication between the two executable projects.

When testing my two programs, I notice that they run without needing the class library (DLL) located in the same directory.

What is happening here?  Do I need to distribute the DLL if only constants are used from it?

Comment: You may not need `const` values, because they're hard coded into the call-site at compile-time, but you should certainly need class definitions...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they are *genuine* constants, introduced with `const`, then the value of each constant will be inlined where it's used. For example, if you have:

```
// Assembly1
public static class Constants
{
    public const string Foo = "Hello";
}

// Assembly2
public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Constants.Foo);
    }
}
```

... then the value "Hello" will be inlined into Assembly2 and you don't need Assembly1 to be present. No code will refer to it, even if it's still listed as a reference within Assembly2.

However, if you ever access the constants by *reflection* (which is entirely reasonable) then you would want to have Assembly1 present.

Comment: I have found that if I use reflection to decouple two assemblies to the point that they have no explicit references to one another at all, that I then need to manually load the assemblies using `Assembly.Load` (`Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies` does not work either since the references to the assemblies seems to have been optimized out as well.)